# How to write a procedure to square a number in oracledb

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sqr(n IN NUMBER, res OUT NUMBER)
IS 
BEGIN
    res:= n*n;
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE(res);
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('PL/SQL procedure successfully completed');
END;
/

DECLARE
ans NUMBER;
BEGIN
EXECUTE sqr(15, :ans);
END;
/
```

I'm new to SQL, trying to create a query to square a number using procedure i dont know how to do it. i was able to come with code above but for some reason i cant connect to DB!

Help needed. (ignore if there are any mistakes in my que framing)

Answer (score 1):

Code you wrote is ... well, not that bad. With some changes, it *works*:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sqr(n IN NUMBER, res OUT NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4      res:= n*n;
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     ans NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    sqr(15, ans);
  5    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE(ans);
  6  END;
  7  /
225

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

Though, you'd rather create a **function** (instead of a procedure):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_sqr (n in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return n*n;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_sqr(15) ans from dual;

       ANS
----------
       225

SQL>
```

---

But, nothing of that matters because you said

> for some reason **i cant connect to DB!**

That's the real problem, and you shared absolutely no information about it. Which tool did you use? Do you have a database at all? Where is it? On your own computer or on a server (available to you through the network)? How exactly did you try to connect? What did Oracle say?

Comment: I'm trying out to learn SQL via challenges, so what happened is i have to write a stored procedure to square a number! but that's not the trickiest part here, I've been given db address, login, and pw and have been asked to write sql code for the same. (The ide/editor is oracledb standalone).

Comment: _"The ide/editor is oracledb standalone"_  Never heard of an IDE called 'oracledb standalone'.   And I've been working with oracle since 1995.  If you've been given a db address, login, and pw, then you must be using them to connect to the db.  So what result do you get from the connection request?  In any event, your actual problem has no relation to your subject and question.  Best to close this thread and open one focused on your connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to write a procedure for this.

Simply use power(number, to the power of) as below for any desired number e.g 10

`select power(10,2) from dual`;

`select power(10,3) from dual`;

`select power(10,4) from dual`;

Same way use sqrt(NumberToSquare) for getting square root.

`select sqrt(10) from dual`

Remember, it is always recommended to use the oracle inbuilt functions and use the custom procedures or functions only and only if it doesn't fit your requirement.

Comment: The OP is "new to SQL" so I assume this procedure is just an exploration of "how do these things work" - the actual contents don't matter much. But yes, if there is something built-in, then don't reinvent the wheel